# Java Constructor issue - boolean condition

Tags: java

I'm trying to put boolean condition in Constructor.

The task is to create Object only if the condition is true.

In the example below: if `checkInitialPass()` returns false, the Object should not be created.

```
SecuredNotepad(int numPages) {
        super(numPages);
        checkInitialPass();
}
```

Comment: Technically, you're too late: the object has already been created. **But** if you throw an exception in the constructor you can stop the code that constructed it from accessing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible.

You have (at least) two options:

#### 1. Throw an exception

```java
SecuredNotepad(int numPages) {
    super(numPages);
    if (!checkInitialPass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid");
    }
}
```

#### 2. Create a static factory method

Make the constructor private and create a static factory method.

```java
private SecuredNotepad(int numPages) {
    super(numPages);
}

public static SecuredNotepad createInstance(int numPages) {
    if (checkInitialPass()) {
        return new SecuredNotepad(numPages);
    }
    else {
        return null;
        // Or throw exception
    }
}
```

I would go for the factory method which would throw an exception if the *initial pass* failed. Alternatively, if you want to expand it even more, you could use a `SecureNotepadFactory`, as Thomas Timbul mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure if throwing exceptions in the constructor is a good idea. Going for some static `createInstance` method sounds like a much better option.

Comment: Dang you were faster. +1. Or you move the check to the calling code, if encapsulation permits. A `SecureNotepadFactory` might just be the ticket?